# Call Cloud Call from one Parse Application in another Parse application

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, parse-platform, httprequest

I need to call a cloud call in one parse application from the cloud of another parse application through the Rest API.

For this I have this code now. However, I always get the error: com.parse.ParseException: ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined at main.js:12:20. (this line is referring to the line where the XMLHttpRequest is initialized). My code for this is:

```
var url = "https://api.parse.com/1/functions/signUp";

var myObj = new Object();
myObj.age = 45;
myObj.email = "test@gmail.com";
myObj.password = "testpw";

var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open("POST", url);
client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
client.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", "xxx");
client.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "xxx");
client.send(JSON.stringify(myObj));
```

Since this code is executed in the Parse cloud, I think the problem is that the XMLHttpRequest isn't constructed correctly. Could that be?

Is this even possible with Parse, calling a cloud call from a parse application through the rest-api from the cloud from another parse application?

Answer (score 1):

You can make http calls with `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest()`

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  url: 'https://api.parse.com/...',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'X-Parse-Application-Id':'...',
    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key':'...'
  },
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(myObj)
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Give that a shot.  re: https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#networking

You can probably skip the JSON stringify and just pass in myObj.